# I want to show recent post according to category of the post in single.php?

Tags: posts, categories

i have a post of category (BABY HEALTH). In landing page, the recent post should appear according to above post category.
The post may have different categories , i show recent post according to this categories.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried researching about [wp_query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)?

Also here's a basic looping according to category :

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array('post'),
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'category_name' => 'test',
);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
            // Your custom code
    }
} else {
    // no posts found
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: where you add {'category_name' => 'test'}. category name should fetch from above post category. it will change according to post category

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the cat-slug with Baby Health slug.

For Simple Blog Category

```
<?php
    global $post;
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => 10, 'category_name' => 'cat-slug' );
    $posts = get_posts( $args );
    foreach( $posts as $post ){ 
        setup_postdata($post); 
        get_the_title();
        get_the_excerpt();
        get_the_content();
    }
?>
```

For Custom Post Type - Taxonomy

```
$wp_argu = array(
    'post_type' => 'prayer',
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    'suppress_filters' => false,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'slug', // id, name
            'terms'    => 'bob',
        ),
    ),
);

$query = new WP_Query( $wp_argu );
while($query->have_posts()){ 
    $query->the_post();
        get_the_title();
        get_the_excerpt();
        get_the_content();
}
```